How to display user input on-screen and save as a variable for other parts of the webpage
I have the following page created in React. I want to be able to select an option in the drop-down box labeled “Thermocouple 1” and input text in the “User Name” box and click update. Based on what the user has selected in the drop-down menu, I want to display the selection and user input below drop-down and input box. Once I have this matrix(?), I need to be able to share it with all the other pages in my app as well(this is only one page (accessed via a navbar) in the app.
When the user inputs text in “User Name” and clicks update, I want the data displayed below as follows:
Thermocouple 1      Heater 1
Analog 4        Pump Voltage
Digital In 3        Overflow Limit
The code for this page is below. Any help on this would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Codeapp page

    import { useState } from "react";

    export default function Temp() {

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    const [filelist, setFileList] = useState<unknown[]>([]);
    const [userValue, setUserValue] = useState("");
    const [myIndex, setMyIndex] = useState(0);
    const [inputDATA, setInputData] = useState("");

    let userName = [
      ["Thermocouple 1"],
      ["Thermocouple 2"],
      ["Thermocouple 3"],
      ["Thermocouple 4"],
      ["Analog 1"],
      ["Analog 2"],
      ["Analog 3"],
      ["Analog 4"],
      ["Digital In 1"],
      ["Digital In 2"],
      ["Digital In 3"],
      ["Digital In 4"],
      ["Digital Out 1"],
      ["Digital Out 2"],
      ["Digital Out 3"],
      ["Digital Out 4"],
    ];

    var mainArray = ["", ""];

    const addUserName = () => {
      if (userValue !== "") {
        //mainArray.push(userValue);
        // or using spread operator
        mainArray = [...mainArray, inputDATA];
        setInputData("")
        return;
      }
      alert("Field cannot be empty!")
    }

    const addNewFilename = () => {
      const addItems = {
        fileName: inputValue,
        value: inputValue,
      };
      if (inputValue !== "") {
        const addFile = [...filelist];
        addFile.push(addItems);
        setFileList(addFile);
        return;
      }
      alert("Field cannot be empty!")
    };

    const fileRecords =
      filelist.length > 0 &&
      filelist.map((data: any) => {
        return (
          <option value={data.fileName} key={data.fileName}>
            {data.fileName}
          </option>
        );
      });

    return (
      <>
        <h1 className="hdrcenter pb-2">Logging File Setup</h1>

        <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
          <div className="m-2">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Type Log Filename"
              className="input input-bordered min-w-80 max-w-xs"
              onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
            <button
              className="btn justify-right"
              onClick={addNewFilename}>Create File</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="flex items-center justify-center ml-4">
          <select className="select select-bordered m-1 w-80">
            <option disabled selected>Select Log Filename</option>
            {fileRecords}
          </select>
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center ml-1">
            <button className="btn justify-right ">Run Log File</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="divider divider-neutral pt-4 pb-4">User Names</div>

        <div className="flex items-center justify-center pt-2 pb-4 ">
          <select className="select select-bordered ml-4"
            onChange={(e) => setMyIndex(e.target.selectedIndex)}
          >
            <option value="Thermocouple 1">Thermocouple 1</option>
            <option value="Thermocouple 2">Thermocouple 2</option>
            <option value="Thermocouple 3">Thermocouple 3</option>
            <option value="Thermocouple 4">Thermocouple 4</option>
            <option value="Analog 1">Analog 1</option>
            <option value="Analog 2">Analog 2</option>
            <option value="Analog 3">Analog 3</option>
            <option value="Analog 4">Analog 4</option>
            <option value="Digital In 1">Digital In 1</option>
            <option value="Digital In 2">Digital In 2</option>
            <option value="Digital In 3">Digital In 3</option>
            <option value="Digital In 4">Digital In 4</option>
            <option value="Digital Out 1">Digital Out 1</option>
            <option value="Digital Out 2">Digital Out 2</option>
            <option value="Digital Out 3">Digital Out 3</option>
            <option value="Digital Out 4">Digital Out 4</option>
          </select>

          <div className="ml-2">
            {/* <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Type User Name"
              className="input input-bordered w-48"
              //onChange={addNewUsername }
              onChange={(e) => setUserValue(e.target.value)}
            /> */}
          </div>

          <div className="flex ml-2">
            <div className="join">
              <input className="input input-bordered join-item w-48" onChange={(e) => setUserValue(e.target.value)} placeholder="User Name" />
              <button className="btn join-item"
                onClick={addUserName}
              >Update</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div className="flex  justify-center">

          <div className="flex mr-1">
            {userName[myIndex]}
            <div className="ml-14 ">
              {userValue}
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </>
    );
  }




Please see Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.
